# How to save Parity data with docker

Tags: blockchain, parity, docker

Every time I upgrade parity on docker by pulling and creating a new container I lose all sync data.

The Dockerfile doesn't seem to expose a volume I could mount with -v

Is there a trick to it or should I ignore it now that Parity can auto-update (since 1.5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to **mount it on docker** with **-v** to a local folder

### Example

First on your host create the folder where parity is going to save the data

```
mkdir /srv/parity
```

Then make sure you have the latest version of parity

```
docker pull parity/parity:nightly
```

And finally create the container with the following parameters:

- **-v /srv/parity:/root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/** (mount your local folder /srv/parity to the containers parity storage

#### Full run command:

```
docker run -ti -d -p 8545:8545 --name parity -v /srv/parity:/root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/ parity/parity:nightly --jsonrpc-interface '0.0.0.0' --jsonrpc-hosts="all" --author "0xYOURETHADDRESS" --auto-update="all" -d /mnt
```

**Note:** This command will also:

- Allow the JSON RPC interface to be accessed by anyone in your network so **don't use this command on an exposed server**
- Enable the auto-update of Parity which was introduced in 1.5
- Allows you to solo-mine by specifying the "author" parameter

After you ran the command you can verify that everything worked by checking the /srv/parity folder on your docker host

[image: Checking parity folder]

---

## Bonus dev script:

You can use the following bash script to update parity whenever you like. It removes the old container, creates a new but keeps the data

```
#!/bin/sh

docker pull parity/parity:nightly
docker rm -f parity
docker run --restart always -ti -d \
-p 8180:8180 -p 8545:8545 -p 8546:8546 -p 30303:30303 -p 30303:30303/udp \
--name parity --restart always \
-v /srv/parity:/root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/ parity/parity:nightly \
--jsonrpc-interface '0.0.0.0' --jsonrpc-hosts="all" \
--author 0xYOURETHADDRESSHERE \
--auto-update="all" \
--stratum --stratum-interface=0.0.0.0 \
--jsonrpc-cors null \
--unsafe-expose \
--db-compaction hdd \
--mode active --cache-size 4096 \
--ui-interface 0.0.0.0 --ui-no-validation

docker logs --follow parity
```

Comment: Actually the -d means [detached mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d). Did your solution work?

Comment: Parity changed a lot since I wrote this answer so I just updated it to work with current versions. The use of "-d" is discuraged now because it renders parity unable  to perform key generations